# How to integrate XML report into SonarQube database?

Tags: xml, jenkins, sonarqube, maven-surefire-plugin

I need to import test results, covearage and linters from many tools of which Surefire and Cobertura. For the moment, I try with xml files manualy made.

From Jenkins and thoses XML reports I have already configure post action "Analysis sonarqube with Maven".

I'm working with many languages (C, Java, JS) and for each, I wanna import metrics into Sonar. For the moment, the conversion is not automated, so I give a XML file like a mock.

What I want :
- In C language, run unit tests and technicals integration tests,
- In JS language, run unit tests,
- In Java test, run functionnal tests the project has not sources code, this contains only test scripts.

For the question, take only C unit tests. I will integrate other levels and coverage later, when this will be OK. I need to separe metrics (for each type of test)

In Analysis sonarqube with Maven, I specify : `-Dsonar.junit.reportPaths=ut/`

When I build the job I get :

```
[INFO] parsing [/test/tools/pic/workspace/sb_maven/ut]
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=206ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java]
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java] (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
[INFO] 1 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=951ms
[INFO] Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
[INFO] 1/1 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Sensor XML Sensor [xml] (done) | time=336ms
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=32ms
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Calculating CPD for 0 files
[INFO] CPD calculation finished
[INFO] Analysis report generated in 343ms, dir size=584 KB
[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 194ms, zip size=262 KB
[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 88ms
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://10.1.4.126:9000/sonar/dashboard/index/fr.xxxxx:xxxxx
[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[INFO] More about the report processing at http://10.1.4.126:9000/sonar/api/ce/task?id=AWKVT9Sz_3FNXuJjExYZ
[INFO] Task total time: 16.972 s
```

But nothing appears in Sonar

Comment: Have you checked [the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project)?

Comment: Yes, I do this, but has no effect in Sonar UI. Test result does appears

Comment: Then please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question to include things like 1) what you've tried and what the results were (_relevant_ excerpts from analysis logs) 2) what about the docs didn't work for you or that you don't understand.

Comment: In sonar logs I get : `2018.04.05 12:17:46 INFO  ce[AWKVT9Sz_3FNXuJjExYZ][o.s.c.t.CeWorkerImpl] Executed task | project=fr.xxx:xxx | type=REPORT | id=AWKVT9Sz_3FNXuJjExYZ | submitter=admin | time=5266ms`

Comment: Are you using the Cxx community plugin to analyze C or SonarCFamily? Your answer will change the answer you get.

Comment: Analyze (Test report and static review) comes from another tool (Parasoft C++Test). I want to exploit generated reports by it after conversion in [Generic Execution](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data)